# How to make a cat stop coming in the house (But leave it outside!)?

Tags: cats

So we fed a cat last week, and now wherever WE go, it follows us for a purr. However, my mothers allergic to cats we don't want the cat in the house.

The problem is, whenever we open the door, the cat comes in, I'd rather keep it **OUTSIDE**.

How can I stop it from coming inside the house?

Comment: You will learn to block the door.

Comment: @keshlam We keep the door open as the house is isolated

Comment: Unless you want to drive the cat away entirely, I think you have to start closing the door. And windows. Or accept that a cat goes anywhere it is allowed to go.